# SQL inner join gives error

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have two tables, `c_users` and `c_posts`. `c_posts` has a foreign key named `post_author` that references `c_users`.

Example

c_posts :  ID = 17, post_author = 550

c_users : ID = 550, user_login = vsg24

I want to write a query to select the all the posts that have a matching user.

This is what I've tried, but got errors:

```
SELECT c.post_author, d.ID,
FROM c_posts c, c_users d
WHERE c.post_author = d.ID
```

Also tried:

```
SELECT c_posts.post_author, c_users.ID,
FROM c_posts INNER JOIN c_users ON c_posts.post_author = c_users.ID
```

What am I doing wrong? (edit: screenshot included)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQSbc.jpg
F
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5yio.jpg

Comment: Also, for future reference, its best to include the error ! :)

Comment: Take a look at the error. It will say error near 'from c_posts'. Look there and see the extra comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the errors were because of the extra `,` after the selection fields.

```
SELECT p.post_author, u.ID 
FROM c_posts p
INNER JOIN c_users u ON p.post_author = u.ID
```

Comment: Mysql Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1